# CSS - center image and show shadow on top

Tags: html, css

I have a image in a div having id `container` but it is messing the things up. It is not centering plus the box-shadow is not shown on image. I added `margin:auto` but It did not helped me. I think `margin:auto` centers all fixed-width elements but in my case, you know image is resized by CSS. Any other solution ? Maybe absolute positioning work but the container height will get zero. I don't want to use Javascript/jQuery.

I have this [bin](http://jsbin.com/ozAH/1/edit) for ya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin:auto` but also add `display:block`:

```
#container > img {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:550px;
  height:auto;
 display: block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want the image to overrun your shadow, do this:

```
#container > img {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:542px;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  margin:4px auto 4px;
}
```

Comment: Nice! can you explain your code? Plus what is the problem with `box-shadow` ?

Comment: `margin:auto` only works on elements with display block, so any element which is not block by default needs this attribute set. Regarding the shadow, you only give it to container, no shadow on image?!

Comment: Oh yeah! That can be done on image. I have to add `box-shadow` property for image and am I wrong that for `margin:auto` element should be fixed-width ?

Comment: I know image can have box-shadow, i was just asking if that's what you want (since you already have one for the container), and yes, you need fixed width for margin:auto to work

Answer (score 0):

try   `margin-left:auto margin-right:auto`

Comment: Hey, `margin:auto` is short for the code you provided. Nothing is gonna change.

Comment: Plus omitting the semi-colons between property-values and the next property is a syntax error, and would (almost certainly) prevent any subsequent style rules for that element from being applied.